# CSS3/jQuery transitions not working in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, css, css-transitions

Is anyone else having issues with FF not rendering jQuery and CSS3 transitions. For instance, the following site's demo doesn't work in FF, but does in Chrome and Safari. FF used to work but recently it doesn't. I've tried on multiple computers and both have this issue.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Post your code/JSFiddle.

Comment: There isn't one. I'm not looking for a fix, just wondering if anyone is having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assuming here, but maybe that plugin is based on `-moz-transition` and the latest firefox might have dropped support for it in favor of `transition`? I shall investigate further

EDIT FF16 changed as assumed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition

EDIT 2: as this is the accepted answer, I am incorporating the comment below - credit to @Boris Zbarsky:

> Firefox hasn't dropped support for -moz-transition or -moz-transform. It added support for transition and transform alongside it. But jquery.transit is just broken in any browser that supports transform without a prefix. See http://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/issues/86 and http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807636

Comment: Ah! That must be it. I'll check my code for another site which has the same issue. You'd think they would still support -moz, though, so that we don't all have to go change our previous code. :(

Comment: I believe the idea of not supporting it anymore is sound, the best way is always to have vendor-specific ones first, then the W3C recommended one last - so it will be always picked up by browsers that still suppor the prefixed version too! Sometimes the proposed syntax changes a lot too and that is a pain - i.e. css gradients

Comment: Firefox hasn't dropped support for `-moz-transition` or `-moz-transform`.  It added support for `transition` and `transform` alongside it.  But jquery.transit is just broken in any browser that supports `transform` without a prefix.  See https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/issues/86 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807636

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have -webkit-, -moz-, and unprefixed versions of the CSS properties in question (or that the jQuery plugin is generating them as needed).

Firefox 16 removed the requirement for the -moz- prefix for 2D transforms.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Don't forget `-o-` and `-ms-` (and maybe even `-khtml-`) versions too.

Comment: How frustrating. They should have at least made it backwards compatible for those of us who previously had that. Now I'll need to go back through all my previous sites and make sure they have the non-prefixed versions as well. Grrrr....

Comment: We _did_ make it backwards compatible as long as you're being reasonable about it!  But the code in this library is not reasonable: it goes out of its way to be broken.